# When allowing a sender or sender domain in outlook does that apply to the "via" as well?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

The company I work for sends emails for an internal email, but it is sent through a third party service and is authenticated with our domain. Surprisingly, one of our emails ended up in my junk folder, and at the top of the email in Outlook it showed the following information

> SomeAccount someaccount@somedomain.com(SomeAccount via somedomain.com)

One thing that seemed odd to me is why the message was marked as possible spam to begin with since it's a message from someone at somedomain.com and it was authenticated via somedomain.com and all the links in the email go to sites at somedomain.com and my email address account is with somedomain.com

Oddities aside, I figured I needed to add to my safe sender list, but that got me thinking about the specifics of the safe sender list. If I select `Never Block Sender's Domain (@example.com)` does that just apply to the sender like `someaccount@somedomain.com`, or does it also apply to the via information? For example, if I got an email from `whoever@somedomain.com` via `stealyourmoney.com` I would expect that to be categorized as potential spam, but if `@somedomain.com` was on the safe sender list, would it get through just because it was on the list and properly authenticated by someone?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, [Outlook safe senders list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-the-junk-email-filter-5ae3ea8e-cf41-4fa0-b02a-3b96e21de089) works based on the email address, Email addresses and domain names in the Safe Senders List are never treated as junk email, regardless of the content of the message. So, personally I think, the key of your issue should be related to what your senders' email address look. I cannot reproduce the “via” operations to test, if possible, it would be suggested for you to test via your third party service for a more accurate answer.

[image]

By the way, in order to help improve spam filters, you could also try using the [Report Message add-in](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-report-message-add-in-b5caa9f1-cdf3-4443-af8c-ff724ea719d2) to offer feedbacks.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Thanks for your understanding and support.